# LINQ Query Issue with using Any on DocumentDB for child collection

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

Using v1.8 .Net SDK

Trying return Sales where the Sale client array contains the Client ID I’m looking for.

```
Sales.Where(sale => sale.Clients.Any(c => c.ClientId == clientID));
```

Returns Error
"Nullable object must have a value."

at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ThrowIfExceptional(Boolean includeTaskCanceledExceptions)
at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.GetResultCore(Boolean waitCompletionNotification)
at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.get_Result()
at Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Linq.DocumentQuery`1.GetEnumerator()
at System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection)
at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)

ClientID is a GUID, but trying to query any property on the client object returns the same error.

If I run the same query on the same data but just using a List collection (i.e. not using DocumentDB) then all is fine.

Any advice appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: Can you add an example documents to the question?

Comment: DocumentDB does not support ANY - see https://feedback.azure.com/forums/263030-documentdb/suggestions/11503872-support-linq-any-or-where-for-child-object-collect

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This query can be alternatively expessed using SelectMany + Where:

```
Sales.SelectMany(s => s.Clients.Where(c => c.ClientID == clientID).Select(c => s));
```

Comment: Just out of curiousity, how would you write something like this in the document DB sql syntax?

Comment: Very similar because both DocumentDB SQL and LINQ work over objects: SELECT sale FROM sale JOIN client IN sale.clients WHERE client.clientId = "c"

Comment: Excellent, great work. I never considered c => s before to get back to the "outer" entity. Thanks.

Comment: Is this possible using the from..select..where Linq syntax?