# DocumentDB LINQ match multiple child objects

Tags: c#, linq, azure-cosmosdb

I have a simple document.

```
{
    Name: "Foo",
    Tags: [
        { Name: "Type", Value: "One" },
        { Name: "Category", Value: "A" },
        { Name: "Source", Value: "Example" },
    ]
}
```

I would like to make a LINQ query that can find these documents by matching multiple `Tags`.

i.e. Not a SQL query, unless there is no other option.

e.g.

```
var tagsToMatch = new List<Tag>()
{
    new Tag("Type", "One"),
    new Tag("Category", "A")
};

var query = client
    .CreateDocumentQuery<T>(documentCollectionUri)
    .Where(d => tagsToMatch.All(tagToMatch => d.Tags.Any(tag => tag == tagToMatch)));
```

Which gives me the error `Method 'All' is not supported.`.

I have found examples where a single property on the child object is being matched: [LINQ Query Issue with using Any on DocumentDB for child collection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38275668/linq-query-issue-with-using-any-on-documentdb-for-child-collection)

```
var singleTagToMatch = tagsToMatch.First();

var query = client
    .CreateDocumentQuery<T>(documentCollectionUri)
    .SelectMany
    (
        d => d.Tags
            .Where(t => t.Name == singleTagToMatch.Name && t.Value == singleTagToMatch.Value)
            .Select(t => d)
    );
```

But it's not obvious how that approach can be extended to support matching multiple child objects.

I found there's a function called ARRAY_CONTAINS which can be used: [Azure DocumentDB ARRAY_CONTAINS on nested documents](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40683533/azure-documentdb-array-contains-on-nested-documents)

But all the examples I came across are using SQL queries.

This [thread](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/a951a271-e729-474b-bf04-ed4d413cb096/arraycontains-using-in-linq?forum=AzureDocumentDB) indicates that LINQ support was "coming soon" in 2015, but it was never followed up so I assume it wasn't added.

I haven't come across any documentation for `ARRAY_CONTAINS` in LINQ, only in [SQL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/documentdb-sql-query-reference#bk_array_contains).

<s>I tried the following SQL query to see if it does what I want, and it didn't return any results:</s>

```
SELECT  Document
FROM    Document
WHERE   ARRAY_CONTAINS(Document.Tags, { Name: "Type", Value: "One" })
AND     ARRAY_CONTAINS(Document.Tags, { Name: "Category", Value: "A" })
```

According to the [comments on this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35139132/310988), `ARRAY_CONTAINS` only works on arrays of primitives, not objects. SO it appears not to be suited for what I want to achieve.

It seems the comments on that answer are wrong, and I had syntax errors in my query. I needed to add double quotes around the property names.

Running this query did return the results I wanted:

```
SELECT  Document
FROM    Document
WHERE   ARRAY_CONTAINS(Document.Tags, { "Name": "Type", "Value": "One" })
AND     ARRAY_CONTAINS(Document.Tags, { "Name": "Category", "Value": "A" })
```

So `ARRAY_CONTAINS` does appear to achieve what I want, so I'm looking for how to use it via the LINQ syntax.

Comment: this isn't too hard.  You need for the class Tag to implement IComparable which compares multiple tags.

Comment: @jdweng And the DocumentDB LINQ provider understands how to convert that custom IComparable in to the right SQL query?

Comment: There is some [indication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/documentdb-sql-query) that `Contains` is supported, so I'm wondering if `.Where(d => d.Tags.Contains(singleTagToMatch))` works? Because if it does, we can eventually build dynamically `&&` predicate expression similar to what you have used inside the SQL query.

Comment: @IvanStoev That's a very good thought thanks! I'll do a bit of investigation and see what .Contains produces.

Comment: @IvanStoev calling query.ToString translates the query to the SQL it'll send to the back end. And looking at that SQL `.Where(d => d.Tags.Contains(singleTagToMatch));` produces `WHERE ARRAY_CONTAINS(root["Tags"], {"Name":"Type","Value":"One"})` which is perfect! I'm now investigating dynamiclly building LINQ predicates.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Using `.Contains` in the LINQ query will generate SQL that uses `ARRAY_CONTAINS`.

So:

```
var tagsToMatch = new List<Tag>()
{
    new Tag("Type", "One"),
    new Tag("Category", "A")
};

var singleTagToMatch = tagsToMatch.First();

var query = client
    .CreateDocumentQuery<T>(documentCollectionUri)
    .Where(d => d.Tags.Contains(singleTagToMatch));
```

Will become:

```
SELECT * FROM root WHERE ARRAY_CONTAINS(root["Tags"], {"Name":"Type","Value":"One"})
```

You can chain `.Where` calls to create a chain of `AND` predicates.

So:

```
var query = client.CreateDocumentQuery<T>(documentCollectionUri)

foreach (var tagToMatch in tagsToMatch)
{
    query = query.Where(s => s.Tags.Contains(tagToMatch));
}
```

Will become:

```
SELECT * FROM root WHERE ARRAY_CONTAINS(root["Tags"], {"Name":"Type","Value":"One"}) AND ARRAY_CONTAINS(root["Tags"], {"Name":"Category","Value":"A"})
```

If you need to chain the predicates using `OR` then you'll need some expression predicate builder library.

Comment: Thanks for the great answer, this solved the problem for me. I hope you don't mind, I've expanded answer to give more detail and examples.

Comment: You are welcome, glad it helped :) And sure (actually thank you), explanations are not my best strength :)

Comment: So how does this work if you only want one of the elements (name or value) to match? I tried overriding Equals on the Tag class and with EqualityComparer<Tag> on one of the elements/properties and this does not work.

Comment: @carens The things you tried work only in LINQ to Objects. I can't test now, but you could try combining `Select` + `Contains`, e.g. `query.Where(s => s.Tags.Select(t => t.Name).Contains(tagToMatch.Name));`

Comment: I get an error saying the Select method is not supported. I tried a bit with SelectMany, but then I get duplicate results.