# DocumentDB Linq query by object property in list

Tags: c#, linq, azure, azure-cosmosdb

I'm trying to follow the solution presented [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38888343/1439862), but still no success:
This query returns `null`:

```
  var plan = _dbClient.CreateDocumentQuery<Plan>(_collectionUri)
            .SelectMany(p => p.Users.Where(u => u.Id == userId)
            .Select(u => p))
            .AsEnumerable()
            .FirstOrDefault();
```

Although this returns the document I'm searching for (I'm trying to not leave the `AsEnumerable` before the `Where`:

```
  var plan = _dbClient.CreateDocumentQuery<Plan>(_collectionUri)
            .AsEnumerable() 
            .Where(p => p.Users.Any(u => u.Id == userId))
            .FirstOrDefault();
```

This is how the document looks like:

```
{
"id": "9710ef23-aae5-4215-a45b-641185140722",
"title": "Free Plan",
"planId": "freeplan",
"ranking": 1,
"description": "Most basic features",
"startFrom": "2018-01-01",
"monthlyCost": 0,
"details": [
  // supressed
],
"users": [
    {
        "id": "11111111-2222-333-4444-5555555555555",
        "enrolledIn": "2017-07-30 08:00:01"
    },
    {
        "id": "4760c977-6bcf-497d-96eb-c43e5bcf1ab9",
        "enrolledIn": "1981-07-05 08:00:01"
    }
],
```

}

Thank you in advance!

Comment: So, does `userId` equal any record's `Id`, case and all?

Comment: Don't use the SDK like that. Synchronous LINQ calls will send many paged requests over the wire and block your thread. Use the .ExecuteAsync method instead. [Cosmonaut](https://github.com/Elfocrash/Cosmonaut) explains how to do that.

Comment: @CodeCaster that was a good insight. I fixed the problem renaming the `id` in `User` by `UserId`. That `id` is actually coming from an external agent, and calling it `Id` definitely caused some confusion when making the query.

Comment: @NickChapsas I see that you are promoting the library you created. It looks nice, but this project is really small and I would like to keep it "plain" (without external libraries) unless strictly necessary. I might use in the future.

Comment: @luizs81 It has the same dependencies as the library you are referencing (which is an external library), but yeah, just don't do `.FirstOrDefault()` or `ToList()` on `CreateDocumentQuery`'s `IQueryable` because it's a pretty big mistake.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, I tested your first LINQ query and it works well for me.

[image]

You need to check if the case issue in your object corresponds to LINQ.

[image]

Secondly, I tested your second LINQ query and leave the `AsEnumerable` before the `Where`. It occurred errors: `Method 'Any' is not supported.`

Please check the [LINQ to SQL API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/sql-api-sql-query), I suggest you make sql with ARRAY_CONTAINS.

Hope it helps you.

Comment: I fixed the problem renaming the `id` in `User` by `UserId`. That `id` is actually coming from an external agent, and calling it `Id` definitely caused some confusion when making the query. (I thought that not inheriting from `Document` could be the issue, but it's not related).
About the error in `Any`, this is really weird, as once you converted to Enumerable, you should have access to all Linq extensions, event the ones not supported by DocumentDb

Comment: @luizs81 You find Any in the above LINQ support list?

Comment: Yes, as far as I can understand. For example, if you create a `List` of objects, you can use `Any()` to query over the objects in the list.